# Aumentar velocidade do módulo bluetooth HC-05

Tags: c, arduino, bluetooth

Olá, tenho um projeto com Arduino e com o módulo Bluetooth HC-05 que recebe os MACS de dispositivos Bluetooth em volta (não conecta, só busca). Ele funciona, mas gostaria que tivesse um melhor desempenho captando, por exemplo, dispositivos que passem rapidamente pelo HC-05 (no momento ele só capta o BT se o slave estiver perto por pelo menos uns 2 segundos). Ou seja, gostaria que ele trabalhasse mais rapidamente, captando por exemplo, se o dispositivo ficar por 1 segundo na área de alcance do HC-05.

- Primeiramente, tentei ajustar o baude-rate (de 9600 a 1382400) da comunicação serial com o módulo, mas testei e não influencia em nada ou quase nada.
- Depois, tentei ajustar o período e a duração do processo de busca pelo comando AT+IPSCAN, mas, para qualquer valor que ajusto, também produzem resultados bem semelhantes.

Pensei que poderia não estar configurando os parâmetros, mas testei com "AT+IPSCAN?" e "AT+UART?" e os valores que aparecem são os que ajustei.

Achei estranho isso, mas não consegui achar a solução. Alguém sabe o que poderia ser?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ser mais de eletrônica do que de programação, então acho que não se encaixa no escopo do site. Você pode ser mais sobre isso fazendo o [tour], lendo o guia de [ask] ou acessando a [help].

Comment: Eu acho que tem haver com a própria construção do dispositivo, se possível leia o datasheet deve ter algo sobre isso. E como o Anderson falou está um pouco fora do escopo do site. Entra nesse aqui https://www.hardware.com.br/comunidade/.